# Magento: Linking to different store urls

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url, products, stores

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Current Store Setup:

- **Website Name:** Main Website
- **Store Name:** Main Website Store
- **Store View Name:** English, Indonesia

I'm planning to run adwords on each country.

How do I link to the products of these stores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the store views have the same base URLs, you have to use the `___store` parameter:

```
example.com/example-product?___store=english
```

(assuming that the store **code** is "english")